# Can I disable a Word button when opening a document from a console application?

Tags: c#, ms-word, console-application

I'm working with a console application on C#, that receives a document path and open it on Microsoft Word 2010

```
Word.Application oWordApp = new Word.Application();
        DisableSaveAsButton(oWordApp);
        oWordApp.Visible = true;

        try
        {
            Word.Document doc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(docFile);
            doc.Activate();
        } catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error opening document\n"+ e.ToString() + "\n" +e.StackTrace);
        }
```

where docFile is the .doc file path.

I would like to open Word, and the Save As button to not be activate, greyed out and unusable. I found the DisableSaveAsButton method over there, it would be like this:

```
private void DisableSaveAsButton(Word.Application oWordApp)
    {
        Object MenuBar = 40;
        Object FileMenu = 1;
        Object SaveAsButton = 5;
        var saveAsBtn = oWordApp.CommandBars[MenuBar].Controls[FileMenu].accChild[SaveAsButton] as CommandBarButton;

        saveAsBtn.Enabled = false;
    }
```

But it wont work. From what I've read, most people find this solution by editing a Ribbon1.xml on their projects, but my program is a console application with Word functions, not a Word add-in, and it doesn't have any ribbon xml files. So I was wondering, it is posible to disable the Save As button from a console application (requirement from boss), instead of using an add-in with its own template?

Comment: Have you read [this MS post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_2007/how-to-disable-save-as-in-word/fa058f03-259c-4137-8c73-fc7f311cff97) which covers how to render those functions doing nothing - and you could throw a box saying "this option is disabled" or something

Comment: I've considered it, but before I want to know if it is not posible to disable the button itself. Also, I don't really understand the context of that post you linked. The code snippets make sense, but I wouldn't know what to do with it or where to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you found is old technology - pre-Word 2007. The CommandBar object has been superceded by Ribbon XML and the old commands for disabling functionality no longer work. This was a conscious design decision by Microsoft.

In the newer, Ribbon interface only code running in-process can also affect the user interface. So what you want to do is not possible, at least not without also loading a VBA or VSTO add-in.

If you don't want users to be able to save their work, then a "Reader" would appear to be a better approach than using the full-blown Word application, which is first and foremost an *editor*. Better, perhaps, to save the documents to PDF file format then open them in Acrobat Reader, for example.

Comment: Very helpful information. The idea was to let users edit and save the document, but not to allow them to save copies. All the changes should be made on the openned document, so I wanted to disable _Save As_ but let _Save_ enabled.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you can do something with the DocumentBeforeSave event? That has a UI parameter that lets you determine whether the UI should be shown. I can't test right now, but I think you should be able to use that to prevent any "Save As" and only your code takes care of Save. Note that the event is for the entire Word application so you'd also want to check which document is triggering it (also a parameter of the event).